# Generating a fixed success or failure rate in C

Tags: c

I am trying to generate a success or failure percent using the rand() function in C. This is the snippet from what is expected "Good soil plots appear 30% of the time, with poor soil plots appearing 70% of the time. Use the rand() function to decide which plot should appear." I figured using (something % a number) would do it, but I am stuck.

Comment: How many times out of 10 is 30%? Can you turn that into something you can use?

Comment: I see what you are saying, 10 x .3 = 3 and the same for 7, Would something like "success = (rand() % 3) or failure = (rand() % 7);" work?

Comment: NPE's answer is definitely better with the bias fixed. I was going for an easy logic approach that if you have numbers from 1 to 10, 1-3 constitute 30%. You know how to generate numbers in a range and you can see where in the range they fall in order to see whether they should be counted as 30% or 70%. The main problem with that approach is that while it might be easy to see, it has bias.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.) < .3) {
   /* good soil */
} else {
   /* poor soil */
}
```

Here, `rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.)` produces a pseudo-random number uniformly distributed on `[0, 1)`. We compare this number to `.3` to get good soil 30% of the time.

Comment: Thanks! You were a lot more clear and helpful than the book I am using. I actually do understand it a lot better as well.